# Query to group and create a group total

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

My table is like this

```
id     views     country    
1       44        A
2       43        A
3       899       B
4       242       A
5       3204      B
etc.
```

I want to count how many times a country is occurring.

For example in above case country A is occurring 3 times. So for my query I want to be able to correctly show the how many times each record is occurring, but in addition to the count I want to add the views also. In above case I want that country A is occurring 3 times and with views as the sum of `44 + 43 + 242 = 329`, but my query displays only the first views output: `44`.

Here is my query

```
 SELECT count( * ) value, country, concat( country , '_', views ) prod 
 FROM tableA
 GROUP BY prod
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT country, COUNT(*), SUM(views) FROM tableA GROUP BY country
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa3e4/1/0).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    count( * ) value, 
    country, 
    concat(country , '_', SUM(views)) prod 
FROM
    tableA 
GROUP BY country
```